# Truffle with weird behavior dealing with uint type of variables

Tags: solidity, ganache, truffle-migration, truffle-compile, uint256

I´ve spent a couple weeks try to understanding what was heppening. The same solidity code worked great in REMIX but not in Truffle/Ganache. Let´s me explain. I wrote a code bases on Openzeppelin, but it isn´t the same. I changed variables, names, functions. I kept variable as private and I used public functions to access them, I think is a kind of Ethereum propposal. So I had the abstract contract below, just inheritance and constructor is necessary to solve the problem.

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata, IPTK{

    string private name_;
    string private symbol_;

    uint8 private decimals_;
    uint8 private withdrawnDaily_;
    uint256 private totalSupply_;   

    mapping(address => uint256) private withdraw_;

    mapping(address => uint256) private balances_;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed_;


   constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _totalSupplyMinted, uint8 _withdrawnDaily) {
    name_ = _name;
    symbol_ = _symbol;
    decimals_ = _decimals;
    totalSupply_ = _totalSupplyMinted;
    withdrawnDaily_ = _withdrawnDaily;
    }
```

Then I create a contract based on that ERC20.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "./tokens/ERC20.sol";

contract Sample3 is ERC20 {

    constructor() ERC20("Sample3", "SP3", 18, 58000000000, 1) {    
    }
}
```

As I told, in Remix it works great. The ERC20 initializes all private variables with right values, but when use truffle/ganache I got the problem. The values are inicializates with wrong numbers as you can see...

[image: truffle-ganache mirate]

After many and many tests I found out that the problem happened with all uint´s variables. Example, uint8 (decimals_ variable) works great with numbers until 12, after that then doesn´t matter with number iss passed, it will keep 12 as a maximun value. Something similar occurs with uint256 (totalSupply_ variable) and I guess with all uint types.

Does anyone has faced something like that? What could be happening?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the code you use to pass those numbers to the creation of the contract, as that's likely where your issue lies

Comment: But the code is that "ERC20("Sample3", "SP3", 18, 58000000000, 1)" with a pass to " constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _totalSupplyMinted, uint8 _withdrawnDaily)".

Comment: I coded some script to test the values in truffle and it worked great. So, the problem is how ganache pop up the result, I guess.